# z-index and CSS issues

Tags: css, z-index

How do I set a specific section of a page (div section?) to be on top of another section? I tried adding a z-index on the CSS file but it's not working. Or maybe I'm adjusting the wrong CSS file. In the end, I am confronted with:

--- which CSS file do I adjust? (I'm using Firebug but now I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly
--- what exact code adjustments do I need to do?

This is a sample page: http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/offences/aggravated-assault. The testimonial box to the lower right part of the page gets covered by the brown area when you scroll down. The goal is to put it on top so it's not covered whenever you scroll down (I know I should better position it "absolute" instead, but that's not the goal).

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Finally had it solved! Many thanks to all your comments below. Although some answers did not exactly solve the problem, there were concepts behind them that really helped.

Comment: The file itself is mostly irrelevant (as long as it's referenced at all). You need to put the `z-index` into a *rule* that targets the desired element. Then, make sure that value is higher than any `z-index` values that target elements that would otherwise occlude it.

Comment: This may also be an issue with stacking contexts - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys! Will look into these as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `z-index:21` on the div with id `it_widget_content-11-background-wrapper` which is the main container of the sidebar widget. That should solve the issue.

Comment: I'm curious... is there a reason why it's "21" and not any other high number? And yes, I'm also having a hard time locating the CSS file that has the settings for that ID.

Comment: Well, because 21 is the minimum number which solves your issue. Just avoiding high z-index number.

Comment: You don't need to assign any styles to that id. Just locate the div with the id and assign this style to one of the class which is unique to it. That div has these classes: widget-background-wrapper sidebar-widget-2

Comment: I'm intrigued with how you came up with 21 as the minimum number that can solve the issue. I tried that number and it did work! But when I tried 20, it gave me the best result because I wanted the footer to be on top of the testimonial box when you scroll down. You weren't just guessing a number. How did you do that? Thanks btw!

Comment: First scroll to the bottom, when your footer overlaps the concerned div, start increasing z-index value until the div is on the top of footer. That's how I got 21. Reduced the height of browser window for that first

Comment: hahaha. so it was trial and error? I thought there was an instant way to do it. I guess locating the correct CSS file would also inevitably require trial and error. thanks so much! :)

Comment: Yup, it did. I already updated my question to indicate that problem has already been solved. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed` on the classes

**CSS file** - `wp-content/themes/Criminal-Lawyers-it/style.css`

`sidebar-widget-1`

and

`sidebar-widget-2`

They will remain in place.

Just realised it may not be exactly how you want it to look :) However, even with correct z-index, it may look weird having them overlap the footer...

Comment: thanks. Is this the same as positioning them as "absolute" so that they move along with the page when scrolling (and therefore would present no conflict with the brown area)? I know it's a better option but I've no approval to do that yet. Gotta keep it fixed as instructed.

Comment: This is different, positioning them "absolute" will take them out of the normal flow... [here is a good rundown](http://www.cssilluminated.com/general.php). Currently these widgets are contained in a `div` that is floated to the right. The content on the left is floated to the left.

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to test this out because the footer is indeed something to consider. But I am so lost on what CSS files to check for these elements. Will keep checkin...

Comment: Here is the CSS file - `wp-content/themes/Criminal-Lawyers-it/style.css` - Line 350 and Line 357 have `position:fixed` that can be removed along with `top`, `z-index` and `left`. :)

Comment: Okay, I found the files to adjust (more like via trial and error) and it still didn't work. When I removed the positioning, it acted like as though "absolute" - as in the sidebar moves along when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, to this `widget-background-wrapper sidebar-widget-2` add `z-index:9999`. *sorry i would rather comment this, but reputation < 50.*

Comment: I am having an issue locating what CSS file has that element.

Comment: style.css:354, add `z-index:999;` at the end or you can make another class, including both `widget-background-wrapper` and `sidebar-widget-2`, offtopic but i suggest you to use developer tools in further labor

Comment: @Kamlesh Kushwaha i recommend to use higher numbers, if we look at the element, it's definitly must be on top of everything, and if it's so, 21 will cause problems when in the future another elements will be added, and you would again do the same work again

Comment: This one worked! Many thanks! I have to take into consideration the footer though because it can't be under the testimonial box. But now I know what to do next :)

Comment: if you solved, why not mark one of this sugessted answers as helped so other people would save time

Comment: sorry for that. I thought updating the question to indicate that the issue is now solved is the way to do it. marking answers is by clicking on the check icon, right? Already done.